# EF Core - the best way to define collection

Tags: entity-framework-core

I use EF Core 8.0 and have the following class (no matter content for my question):

```
public class DownloadCenterFile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //....

    public int FolderId { get; set; }
    public virtual DownloadCenterFolder DownloadCenterFolder { get; set; }
}
```

and a linked class `DownloadCenterFolder` with collection of `DownloadCenterFile` inside.

What is the best way to define this collection?

Like this:

```
public class DownloadCenterFolder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public required string FolderName { get; set; }

    private ICollection<DownloadCenterFile> _downloadCenterFiles;
    public virtual ICollection<DownloadCenterFile> DownloadCenterFiles 
    { 
        get => _downloadCenterFiles ??= new List<DownloadCenterFile>(); 
        protected set => _downloadCenterFiles = value; 
    }
}
```

or rather like this:

```
public class DownloadCenterFolder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public required string FolderName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DownloadCenterFile> DownloadCenterFiles 
    {
        get; 
        protected set; 
    } = new List<DownloadCenterFile>();
}
```

It's probably equivalent approaches, but looks like the first approach is init collection by demand, while second when object is created, and the second seems less effective...